# A line which is parallel to $y=x$ is rotated about the point $(2,0)$ through 15 degrees anti-clockwise.

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

> Find the y intercept of the line passing through the point of intersection of new line with y=x and at right angles to the new line

Since $y=x$ doesn’t pass through(2,0) I can only think of the line being shifted about (2,2). If I am wrong, it’s here.

The new angle becomes 60 degree with +x axis.

The slope of line perndicular to the new line is 
$\frac{-1}{\sqrt 3}$

It passes through (2,2) then 
$$y-2=\frac{-1}{\sqrt 3}(x-2)$$
$$x+y\sqrt 3 -2\sqrt 3 -2=0$$
So the y intercept is 
$$y=\frac{2+2\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 3}$$

But the answer is $y=4+2\sqrt 3
$

Comment: I agree with @MattSamuel in general, but the correct answer (verified with GeoGebra) is the one where the parallel line does pass through (2,0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since new line is from point (2,0) and inclined at angle of π/3 with +ve x axis. Line is y=$\sqrt{3}$(x-2).$$ $$
Intersect line y=x at point A(3+$\sqrt{3}$,3+$\sqrt{3}$).
$$ $$
Line from point A perpendicular to new line will have slope of $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ line is
$$y-(3+\sqrt{3})=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(x-(3+\sqrt{3}))$$
For y intercept put x=0 then $ y=\sqrt{3}+1+(3+\sqrt{3})$
$$y=4+2\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: Yup, drew the diagram wrong. Thanks!